# Is it possible to do a final class immutable in Java?

Tags: java, immutability

Recently on the interview I had an interesting question.
We have mutable class:

```
final class Example {
  private int i;
  private String s;
  private Object o;
  // get, set
}
```

And instance of this class `Example e = new Example();`

Can we somehow make this instance immutable? Without changing original class.

My thoughts:

1. Deep cloning of this instance? But not sure if it's possible.
2. Maybe something like serialization/deserialization?

Comment: It currently is immutable: you can't extend it, and nothing can change the member variables (well, unless it is a nested class, and you're not showing other code which *does* change the variables).

Comment: I would say, from a very picky point of view of course, you can't really have immutability in Java, due to the use of reflection, but that aside from that, this is as close to immutability as you can get.

Comment: @Gavin The class is not immutable because its fields don't have values, but because they're inaccessible.

Comment: @IngoBürk I wasn't saying it was immutable because they have no values, just pointing out they have no values.  Clarified my comment, thanks for the catch :)

Comment: ["Make a class immutable by following these guidelines:"](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29).

Comment: I know how to make class immutable but for example if we can't change original class. I've updated a little bit my question.

Comment: You can't make an instance immutable if it is an instance of a mutable class; you can only stop other classes invoking methods on that instance which mutate it. Being an immutable instance and not being able to mutate the instance are not the same thing.

Comment: I have a funny feeling that the actual interview question was different.

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to make modifications to the `Example` class **and** you cannot subclass it (in your snippet, it is marked as `final`) the closest solution I can think of is to create a wrapper class, which is immutable. This is not a perfect solution, and has it's drawbacks.

First, how to do it:

```
final class ImmutableExample {
  // Redeclare every field as in the Example class
  // but make sure they can't be reassigned 
  // (in this case I'll declare them as final)
  private final int i;
  private final String s;
  private final Object o;

  ImmutableExample(Example mutableExample) {
      // copy fields from original
      this.i = mutableExample.getI();
      this.s = mutableExample.getS();
      this.o = mutableExample.getO();
  }

  // add getters but definitely no setters
}
```

Then everywhere you have code like this:

```
Example e = new Example();
e.setI(42); // etc
```

Change to:

```
Example e = new Example();
e.setI(42); // etc
ImmutableExample immutableE = new ImmutableExample(e);
```

And pass around references to `immutableE`, and make sure that the `e` reference does not escape.

Now, for the drawbacks:

- `ImmutableExample` is not an instance of `Example`, so you cannot pass the immutable type to a method which expects the mutable type, and operations like `if (immutableE instanceof Example)` or `(Example)immutableE` will not work as before
- You have to be very careful that every field of `Example` is also immutable, or `ImmutableExample` will also be mutable. Consider, for example, that the field of type `Object` could be something mutable, like a `HashMap` or a `Date`.
- When the `Example` class changes, you have to repeat the change in `ImmutableExample`.

If it was possible to subclass `Example`, or if it was an interface, this approach might be more useful, but I can't see any other way when `Example` cannot be subclassed.

Answer (score 0):

If each of those fields have getters/setters, then to make it immutable, you will have to

1. Make each field `private` and `final`
2. Make a copy of each field when it's getter is called
3. Remove all setters
4. Any methods within the class that changes it's state must either be removed or use the new getters to access any internals

Comment: The class also mustn't have any method on it that mutates its state.

Comment: The fields should also be final

Answer (score 0):

Immutability is a property of a class not an instance. So besides bytecode twiddling or other means to change the class; not possible.

With a none final class i would create an immutable decorator. That would not make the instance immutable, but provide an immutable wrapper to that instance.

You could not assign the instance to any variable/field, making it impossible to change it ;)